# What's the meaning of こそ in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles

While doing some exercises I found one where I am supposed to insert the correct answer in this dialogue, but I don't understand why it goes こそ。

> マイクさん:「ジャンさん、歌うまいね」
>   ジャンさん:「そんなことないよ。マイクさん…………プロの歌手みたいだったよ」
>   マイクさん:「え、そうかなあ」
>
> 1. なら　　2. でも　　3. こそ　　4. が

Answer (score 15):

「こそ」 is a particle whose main function is to emphasize and accentuate the preceding word or phrase.

> 「マイクさん**こそ**プロの歌手みたいだったよ。」

this sentence means:

> "It was *you*, Mike, who was like a professional singer."

Comment: Grasping こちらこそ at last... thank you!